# Is there any Richard Feynman parallel in mathematics world?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

This is a soft question. I was studying the Red Book by Richard Feynman which consists of his lectures which he delivered in 60's. We all know that what a brilliant teacher an explainer he was. Moreover his lectures consist of almost all the basic Physics which a new Physics aspirant needs. My question is that Is there any Feynman parallel in math world.... i.e., such an author who has written on mathematics in same manner or has written such books which are rigorous as well as motivating... I'll be glad if someone introduces me to such a person(/s).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have the great Walter Rudin

Comment: @Shamim Has Rudin not mainly written textbooks in various areas of analysis?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft you are right

Answer (score 2):

As Shamim said, Walter Rudin is considered one of the great authors.

I would also point you to Terrence Tao, who is both a prolific research mathematician as well as a writer of textbooks. His [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/) contains much that is "rigorous as well as motivating".